# Refresh com php

Tags: php

Tenho um botão que adiciona o valor +1 na base de dados e que mostra o total de "likes" que o artigo já tem.

```
 <a class='btn' href=portal/fav.php?id=".$produto['id']."> <span class='badge  bg-red'>".$produto['fav'] . "</span> <i class='fa fa-heart-o'></i> Likes  </a>
```

Só que desta forma a pagina vai atualizar. 
Como faço, para quando clicar no botão, ele atualizar, sem atualizar a pagina?

A pagina em php que faz o update é

```
fav.php
```

Comment: Você terá que usar um jQuery que faça isso... Que acesse esse fav.php, faça o update e retorne com o numero atualizado. Usando json é bem facinho de fazer... Vou ver se acho um exemplo pra você!

Comment: Nenhuma resposta solucionou o problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa efetuar uma requisição assíncrona, conhecido por AJAX. Utilizando o jQuery, seria algo como:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#fav-add').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        produtoId = $(this).data('id');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'portal/fav.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {id : produtoId},
            success: function(data) {
                alert('Sucesso!')
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Erro!');
            }
        });

    });
});


<a class='btn' id="fav-add" data-id="<?php echo $produto['id'] ?>"> <span class='badge  bg-red'>".$produto['fav'] . "</span> <i class='fa fa-heart-o'></i> Likes  </a>
```

E com o PHP você obtém o ID e faz o tratamento para a atualização do campo:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST)){

    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $query = "UPDATE mytable 
      SET increment = increment + 1 
      WHERE id = $id";

  $this->execute($query);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Da forma como no exemplo abaixo você ira chamar essa função no botão, e na sua pagina fav.php você monta o update, como não terá nada de retorno ou seja um alert ou algo assim pode deixar o success vazio mesmo, agora caso queira fazer algo após o update é só adicionar no success e na  variável data você tem o retorno da fav.php

```
function atualizaLike(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "fav.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {},
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Ocorreu uma falha ao verificar e tente novamente!");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: isso correto apenas chamar a função no onclick.

Comment: Tendo no meu fav.php alguns echos de sucesso e erro so para controlo, como faço para ele ignorar essas mensagens?

Comment: o seu echo estará na variável data do success ai vamos supor que  usar um alert ficaria,                                                                                success: function (data) {        
     alert(data);                                                                                                             }